# Script 105 Unterminated string constant

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
    $( "td.cell" ).hover(function() {
     if(condition)
        $(this).append($("<span> Cell is disabled </span>"));},
   function() {$(this).find("span:last").remove();});
```

Basically I want a span to be shown only when the cell from the table is disabled. The weird stuff is that on one computer is working with ff, but on a different computer with ie and ff as well is giving an unterminated string constant. Tried to concatenate the span to "../sp"+"an.." but it doesn't work. When I inspect the element it code looks like this:

```
        $( "td.cell" ).hover(function() {if(true)
            $(this).append($("<span> Cell is disabled
           //--></span>"));}, function() {$(this).find("span:last").remove();});
```

Comment: Well, for sure it's working, but lets not open a discussion about it. Do you have any idea, how the append should look like then?

Comment: Just remove the new-line ... Btw. Did I edit the code in the post correctly, i.e. it is the same you really have?

Comment: Yes, it's the same, the difference is that the condition is true when running the code. But the new line only appears when I inspect the element, in the code I don't have any new lines, in the parenthesis I have only the span open and close tags, containing my message.